# gnome-terminal won't launch because it crashes every time

Tags: centos, gnome-terminal

gnome-terminal worked this morning, and I haven't installed any software or changed any OS configurations.  Now every time I try to open a terminal window, I get an error dialog: The application gnome-terminal has crashed.  However you don't have installed bug-buddy, the GNOME crash report tool..."

I've tried installing bug-buddy unsuccessfully, but that's beside the point.

I restarted and shut-down/started-up without luck.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled gnome-terminal, and this didn't help either.

Comment: Open xterm and launch gnome-terminal from there, then paste what you see.

Comment: Make a new user on the system, login as that user and try gnome-terinal to make sure the problem is not with some configuration file/setting in your normal login that causes the crash.

Comment: You will also find some errors in your ~/.xsession-errors file.